# Getting a count for each duplicate record in response from SQL query

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have four columns, 2 columns lets say FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME in table PersonalInfo and other 2 columns ADD1 and ADD2 in table AddressDetails. Now what I have to do is I want to know the count for duplicate record for each row considering all 4 columns.How can I do that?

I have 2 approach till now:
1. I iterate each response and compare with the remaining.
2. Do something with query.

I know the first case is worst option because it will take so much of the time. Is there something I can do with query?

I searched and found this:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, count(LAST_NAME) FROM SchemaName.PersonalInfo S GROUP by LAST_NAME;
```

and the basic is working for single column and not for multiple columns.

How can I do it. Please suggest.

Comment: Thank you: I have deleted my previous comments, to cleanup, and will delete this comment soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by all the cols not just last name.

Working fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a76e7e/3

```
SELECT P.fname,P.lname,A.add1,A.add2, count(*) 
FROM PersonalInfo P, AddressDetails A 
Where P.id = A.id
GROUP by P.fname,P.lname,A.add1,A.add2
having count(*) > 1;
```

Join you tables on the id like in above example.

Comment: Its perfectly working fine with table name but not when I use SchemaName.tablename

Comment: Why you need schema name?

Comment: becuase it is predefined in the structure which is given to us. We have to call by that only. There are so many schemas with so many tables.

Comment: yes I am getting this error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-905, SQLSTATE=57014, SQLERRMC=ASUTIME;000000000064;000005000000;SYSTEM PARAMETER, DRIVER=3.68.61

Comment: Himanshu I accepted ur answer. In my case, its very heavy query because data is huge, so I am going through another approach. But for the normal cases it works fine. Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you table PersonalInfo has a primary key and AddressDetails ha a forey key on this primary key ?

```
select t1.FIRST_NAME , t1.LAST_NAME, t2.ADD1 , t2.ADD2, count(*)      NbPossibility 
from PersonalInfo  t1 inner join AddressDetails t2
on t1.idPersonalInfo=t2.idPersonalInfo
group by t1.FIRST_NAME , t1.LAST_NAME, t2.ADD1 , t2.ADD2 
having count(*)>1
```

Il you have not keys for join this tables (anormal):

```
select t1.FIRST_NAME , t1.LAST_NAME, t2.ADD1 , t2.ADD2, count(*)      NbPossibility 
from PersonalInfo  t1 cross join AddressDetails t2
group by t1.FIRST_NAME , t1.LAST_NAME, t2.ADD1 , t2.ADD2 
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Its perfectly working fine with table name but not when I use SchemaName.tablename

Comment: Just wondering why you  added same answer already posted 5  mins later ?

Comment: Because Esperento57 suggestion is also working with the tables. So if someone see in future then he/she can use any of the solution :)

Comment: Not exactly the same code :)   Its a probleme of timeout [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21424265)